# Binary converter in Java

Tags: java, binary

I'm new to Java, I wrote this code but it seems my Professor wants the converter without stacks, arrays or strings. How do you do this? What is one way I can do this? It's for assembly language x86. He wants me to learn how to do this without array stacks or strings. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Converter {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    int number;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack myStack = new Stack(20);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to convert: ");
    number = kb.nextInt();
    do{
        int temp;
        int remainder;
        myStack.push(number%2);
        number = number/2;
    }while(number>0);
    while(myStack.size() > 0)
    System.out.print(myStack.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell your professor that Java has these for a reason.

Comment: use bitwise operations (& and <<)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JAVA written traditional C-Style code for you which does not use any String Arrays or Stacks.

i have made only a few changes to your original code.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number to convert: ");
    int number = kb.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[number/2];
    int k = 0;
    do {
        arr[k++] = number%2;
        number = number/2;
    } while(number > 0);

    /* Print */
    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
8
```

Output:

```
1000
```

Comment: `[]` that's a array.

Comment: I know. But it says not to use *String Arrays*